# I want to remove this line from my html code

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is the image of my html code.

[image]

I want to get rid of the line boxed in red.Please help me.That line does not show in the actual code, but when the page is opened on a browser i.e in (google chrome) and selected "view source code" it shows the line.I want to get rid of it.Please help me, reply me a.s.a.p..Thank you.

Comment: i searched alot about it but did not find the proper solution...

Comment: i guess this comes from a browser extension or it is malware

Comment: holy outdated jquery version, Batman!

Comment: Why don't you just delete it?

Comment: Please include the code in the question. Don't link(!) to a picture (!!).

Comment: thats what..it cannot be deleted. it does not appear on my actual code when i try to edit it in notepad. but when i view source code on browser it appears....Didnt you see the image i uploaded

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Two things: 1. Any code related to your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to follow some random link to help you. If the question doesn't make sense and can't be answered without the link, it's not appropriate for this site. 2. The code must be *code*, not a picture of code. [More](/help/mcve)

Comment: i have uoloaded a image...click on the question

Comment: @AbhiramBakshi: image != code, link != **in** the question

Comment: You are asking how to remove a line of code from a picture. Just delete the line of code you want removed. What are you stuck with?

Comment: that is what i am trying to explain here....if u take a look at the image u might understand

Comment: how do i explain you now....ok if i can send u my php file u will be able to open it on the browser...u will have to use xamp

Comment: Yeah, I think your server may have been compromised, if that isn't part of your source code. You will need to include your code in your question. Or, you have an include somewhere.

Comment: The javascript is included dynamically from another javascript. use the chrome developer console to find initiator of that javascript and remove that code.

Comment: the line is not appearing on my code....i have downloaded the project file and that line shows i have copied it from somewhere....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely adware. Check out: http://www.malwarekillers.com/tag/remove-track-breaking-news/

Comment: Thanx...it was a fking malware....this helped me...:)

Answer (score 0):

As @Tanuel said, this is either from malware or a browser extension since it *seems* that you didn't put it in the source code.

Comment: Thanx...it was a fking malware....

Answer (score 0):

Go to Dev Tools in Chrome (Ctrl+Shift+i) and look at `Network` and check what scripts are being loaded on the page.

Also, take your time to explore the `Elements` tab and to find out how that line is being added to the code.

Comment: Thanx...it was a fking malware....

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad post but I can feel the frustration in your question and the answer is probably just this:

```
<script>
$(document).on('pageload',function()
{
 document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]='';
});
</script>
```

Add it to the bottom of your page.

Comment: Haha! No this won't work because the bad script will have already executed.
The malware is adding the doctype, html, head and script tags to the beginning of the markup and will run before any counter measures can be run.
Check out Luba's solution above.

Comment: Thanx...it was a fking malware....